# How to link_to correct show page from feed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If a user clicks on:

**activities/valuations/_create.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to valuation_path(activity) do %>
  <%= activity.trackable.name %>
<% end %>
```

he is directed to, for example, the error:

> Couldn't find Valuation with 'id'=24

because the valuation is actually 7. This is because this line of code is trying to find the valuation show page by looking at the id number as an activity instead of the id number as a valuation.

To fix it I tried:

```
<%= link_to valuation_path(@valuation) do %>
  <%= activity.trackable.name %>
<% end %>
```

but that gives the error:

> ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Activities#index
>
> No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"valuations",
>   :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

How do we rewrite the code to take the user to the correct valuations show page?

**activities_controller**

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @activities = Activity.order("created_at desc").paginate(:page => params[:page])
    end

    def show
          redirect_to(:back)
    end

  def like
    @activity = Activity.find(params[:id])
    @activity_like = current_user.activity_likes.build(activity: @activity)
    if @activity_like.save
      @activity.increment!(:likes)
      flash[:success] = 'Thanks for liking!'
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Two many likes'
    end  
      redirect_to(:back)
  end
end
```

**activity.rb**

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.per_page = 20
  has_many :notifications
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :trackable, polymorphic: true

  def conceal
    trackable.conceal
  end

  def page_number
    (index / per_page.to_f).ceil
  end

private

  def index
    Activity.order(created_at: :desc).index self
  end
end
```

**activities/index**

```
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
    <%= link_to activity.user.name, activity.user %></b>
    <%= render "activities/#{activity.trackable_type.underscore}/#{activity.action}", activity: activity %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like you want to do a nested resource,

when you have `activities/valuations/_create.html.erb` , that means you should have a nested route

```
#routes.rb
resources :activities do
  resources :valuations
end
```

So your link should be something like

```
<%= link_to 'link', activities_valuataions_path(activity, @validation) %>
```

if you could post your routes

`rake routes`

it should be easy to track down the problem

Comment: Thank you! I tried activity_valuations_path or activity_valuation because those were the too routes given. The former takes me to for example http://0.0.0.0:3000/activities/23/valuations which lists out all the given user's valuations instead of the show page for one. The latter gives an error: `No route matches {:action=>"show", :activity_id=>"23", :controller=>"valuations", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]` You have the right idea though I just can't figure out where we went wrong.

Comment: can u check if @validation has a value or is it just `nil` ? , because it seems like @validation is nil.

Comment: pry(main)> Activity.find(3)
  Activity Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "activities".* FROM "activities" WHERE "activities"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
=> #<Activity:0x007faa56166630
 id: 3,
 user_id: 1,
 action: "create",
 test: nil,
 trackable_id: 1,
 trackable_type: "Valuation",
 created_at: Sun, 31 May 2015 23:11:32 UTC +00:00,
 updated_at: Sun, 31 May 2015 23:11:32 UTC +00:00,
 likes: nil>

Comment: want to chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79279/room-for-anthonygalli-com-and-sameera207

Comment: formatting is better there and quicker to see what im doing wrong here

Comment: Free to chat again @sameera207? Otherwise pick a time or two. I'm flexible just nothing between 3pm - 11pm AEST, which is 1am - 10am EST :)

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com, Im in the chat now :)

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com, Hey sorry not getting back to you . Stuck with some work ;), did u manage to get it going ?

Comment: Yes I did not a problem Sameera! I found the answers here helpful and I took the ball and ran with it from there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627538/how-to-link-to-a-show-page-from-another-mvc :)